# Returning Array from a Function to console.log

Tags: javascript, arrays

So this below is my simple code and i need to display something like ['codigo','codigo']

```js
qtderepeticoes = 3
variavelrepetidora = 'codigo'

function repetition(variavelrepetidora, qtderepeticoes) {
  let resultado = []

  for (let i = 0; i < qtderepeticoes; i++)
    resultado.push(variavelrepetidora)

  return resultado
}

console.log(repetition())
```

What shoud i write to the 'console.log' to show my array?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to pass arguments:

```
repetition(variavelrepetidora, qtderepeticoes )
```

```js
const qtderepeticoes = 3
const variavelrepetidora = 'codigo'

function repetition(variavelrepetidora, qtderepeticoes) {

  let resultado = []

  for (let i = 0; i < qtderepeticoes; i++)
    resultado.push(variavelrepetidora)

  return resultado
}


console.log(repetition(variavelrepetidora, qtderepeticoes))
```

Comment: That's what we call a "typo question". There is no need to answer these types of questions because they are "unlikely to help others with the same problem".

Comment: @CristianoPereiradaSilva usually people spend few days on trying to fix the issue themself before asking on stackoverflow

Comment: @HereticMonkey it's usually really hard to find anything on StackOverflow, built-in search is really bad, using `site:stackoverflow.com` in google helps a little, but not so much.  My process of finding solutions for my problems here is to google my problems in different words until I find something. Closed questions are harder sadly.

Comment: So....how would someone find this question? They would have to have written a function that takes arguments and not passed those arguments in, all the while, expecting an array to show up in a `console.log`. And they'd have to search for something about logging an array, not about taking arguments. This is a helpdesk question, not something Stack Overflow was built for. It's not meant to have every question about every possible error anyone could ever make when programming.

Comment: There are 2,5 million questions with `javascript` tag right now, I guess we can make an answer to every question ever asked with these numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Call your function with 2 arguments, and store the result in a variable result:

```
var result = repetition(arg1, arg2);
```

Console the output:

```
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want default values for your function so you don't have to pass any args;

```
function repetition(variavelrepetidora='codigo', qtderepeticoes=3) {

  const resultado = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < qtderepeticoes; i++)
    resultado.push(variavelrepetidora);

  return resultado;
}

console.log(repetition())
```